# Android Studio + Dragon NaturallySpeaking = focus issues

Tags: windows, android-studio, focus, naturallyspeaking

When I use voice recognition with Dragon NaturallySpeaking as Android Studio is running in the background, Android Studio often gets the focus, which causes the dictation to stop. E.g. if I dictate "Is there any way to display the connection", Dragon might start transcribing only "Is there any" then Android Studio gets the focus, which means that Dragon cannot transcribing anymore (it can only transcribe in the window that has the focus).

There are two ways of "stealing focus" : (1) a window coming to the foreground, and (2) the window receiving keystrokes. In this issue, Android Studio gets the focus according to the 2nd definition, viz. the window receiving keystrokes, but its window does not come to the foreground. I can see in the Windows Taskbar that Android Studio gets the focus:

[image]

but Android Studio's window does not appear.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional and Android Studio 1.0.2 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I have never experienced such an issue with other applications, including IDEs such as Eclipse, Netbeans, Sublime, GNU Emacs, R Studio, Microsoft Visual Studio, IDLE or Matlab.

The issue only occurs when dictating in certain applications such as Google Chrome or Notepad++. It does not occur when dictating in other applications such as Notepad or Kakao Talk.

Demo: http://youtu.be/P9_pV1qq9cI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the bug on the Android Open Source Project's Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=157283